# iOS MMDrawerController objective-c login view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I am begin to study iOS and I try to do left navigation with [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)
my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code is:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


        UIViewController *leftView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
        UINavigationController *leftNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:leftView];



            UIViewController *centerView = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CenterViewController"];
            UINavigationController *centerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:centerView ];
            self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerNav leftDrawerViewController:leftNav];



        self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
        self.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
        self.window.rootViewController = self.drawerController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return YES;
}
```

So it's work fine, but I have `LoginViewController` on my app, and if user has no saved token on `NSUserDefaults`, I must show LogionViewController.
Of course side menu must be hidden on `LoginViewController`.

I Tried to switch to LoginViewController inside my `CenterViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    LoginViewController * vc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.drawerController setCenterViewController:vc withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];



}
```

But I have black screen only.
What I do wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a bit weird because you are setting the new `centerViewController` (of type `LoginViewController`) within the current one (of type `CenterViewController`), and once that is done the latter one will be deallocated because there are no more references to it. This might somehow be causing the black screen.

One solution would be to have the `LoginViewController` outside the `MMDrawerController`, and always present it at the beginning. If there is no token, then quickly (without animation) present the `MMDrawerController` and the `LoginViewController` won't even be seen. This way also allows you to easily dismiss back to the login screen if the user logs out.

Another option is to just present your `LoginViewController` from the `CenterViewController` modally (or however you like really) using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, and then just dismiss it when they log in.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the best way to do? Also I have ForgotPasswordViewController And RegistrationViewController
So there are 3 not MMDrawerViewController.